# How to show that two spin one half particles must form a anti-symmetric wavefunction?

Tags: pauli-exclusion-principle

I am stuck on how to connect the ideas that two spin half particles must form a anti-symmetric wavefunction. Is there a proof on how to show that two spin one half particles must form a anti-symmetric wavefunction?

\begin{align}
\Psi(x_1,x_2)
=
\Psi_1(x_2)
\Psi_2(x_1)
-
\Psi_2(x_1)
\Psi_1(x_2)
\end{align}

This would indeed prove that spin half particles must obey the Pauli Exclusion Principle, because if two fermions were in the same state, then the wavefunction would equal zero.

Comment: Could you be looking for the [spin-statistics theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_statistics_theorem)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think so. All though I do not have enough money to buy the paper : http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10701-009-9351-4 . Sorry.

Comment: I don't think you need to buy any papers. The Wikipedia article itself already offers a full proof of the theorem.

Comment: There is a discussion in Peskin and Schroeder for the specific example of spin one half. If you don't have the money for the book, you could try a library.

Comment: If you're only working with first quantization (not QFT), you can't actually prove it. In that theoretical framework it's a principle in the real sense of the word. Introducing special relativity and allowing second quantization is needed to *prove* it from other first principles.